# UICollectionView different segue for each UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a UICollectionView that loads the cells dynamically but i want to open a diferrent UIViewController when i push the cells.
for example:
-cell1 open UIViewController1
-cell2 open UIViewController2
-cell3 open UIViewController3

Does anybody know, if it possible to make this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a segues from the view controller which holds the collection view (not cell) to the destinations view controllers, for example:

```
UICollectionViewController -> UIViewController1
UICollectionViewController -> UIViewController2
//...etc
```

Remember to add identifier to each segues.

And in the code override `UICollectionViewDelegate` method

```
collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

inside that method check which cell was tapped (indexPath) and if it was cell1 call segue with the right identifier:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("goToVC1Identifier", sender: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it programmatically, something like this in the `UICollectionViewDelegate` method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

```
UIViewController *c = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)indexPath.row]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];
//or however you a moving to next viewcontroller
```

Making sure your viewcontrollers have the correctly named identifiers to match the cells

Answer (score 1):

You will need to perform the segue manually in `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` of the collectionview's delegate.